# What does this borderline ki first Krilin and now Goku get mean?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super episode 76 Krilin had an aura ki we never seen before, it was drawed surrounding very closely his body:

[image]

[image]

Now in the preview of Dragon Ball Super episode 98 we see Goku has the same aura:

[image]

[image]

What does this borderline ki first Krilin and now Goku get mean? It's the only 2 times we've seen this kind of aura in the entire Dragon Ball universe.

Comment: I guess this is basic stage of Ki release shown all Dragon ball, dragonball z series. You can also see in movie Resurrection of F, when Goku fights Frieza without going Super Saiyan or Super Sayian blue form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got an answer to this question in the last episode(98). Basically its just a barrier that is used to protect them against posion, so it cannot make contact with their skin. 
From this we can conclude that it had nothing to do with the aura Krilin has showed us in a previous episode.

Comment: yeah, I saw it. I was expecting someone else to post it, it didnt feel good to post the answer myself unless no one would post one in a long time. Nothing to do with the other ki from krilin, you could also add that

Comment: Sure. The episode ending was one of the darkest stuff that was ever shown in dragonball. Was a bit surreal

Comment: I dont think they really did it. There werent images of aliens screaming, planets breaking apart or exploding. Only shine and one of the angels dubiously smiling

Comment: Yeah that is what makes it surreal, alongside how everyone stopped fighting. But we are getting offtopic here :P